# Bind a method of an object to an event of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want to bind a method of an object to an event of an element. For example:

```
function ABC()
{
   this.events_list = function() {
   }

   this.events_list.clickElement = function() {
      alert("hello world");
   }

   this.bindEvents() = function() {
       $("#element").click(this.events_list.clickElement);
   }
}

var _abc = ABC();
_abc.bindEvents();
```

The above code is not binding the click event to `clickElement` method.

Comment: Have you tried saying `var _abcs = new ABC()` instead? That is, using the "new" keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `#element` exist before you call `_abc.bindEvents()`.  You can wrap it all in

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var _abc = ABC();
    _abc.bindEvents();
});

function ABC()
{
   this.events_list = function() {
   }

   this.events_list.clickElement = function() {
      alert("hello world");
   }

   this.bindEvents() = function() {
       $("#element").click(this.events_list.clickElement);
   }
}
```

Will need to see more of your use case to do more.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.bindEvents() = function() {
```

Take out the first set parentheses, they don't make sense.

```
this.bindEvents = function() {
```

You also need to use `new ABC()` to construct a new `ABC` object; `ABC()` alone will bind `this` to the global object, which is definitely not what you want.

Also, if `this.events_list` is not actually supposed to be a function, but rather a container for other functions, don't make it a function.

```
this.events_list = {};
```

Finally, please remember to use semicolons.

Comment: Hi minitech, thanks for answering.. Actually my original code has all the above mentioned things(except events_list). After that also, it was not working. I just forgot to create the object inside document.ready()

Answer (score 0):

jQuery plugins will save you headache, and they're simple to author:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1" class="clickable" />check me<br />
<div name="item 2" class="clickable">click me<div>
```

to make each of the above items clickable:

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.bindevents = function() {

   events_list = {
    clickElement : function() {
            alert("hello world from " + $(this).attr('name'));
    }
   };

   this.each(function() {
    $(this).bind('click', events_list.clickElement);
   });

 };
})( jQuery );

$('.clickable').bindevents();
```

Comment: There is no reason for the OP's constructor to become a jQuery plugin. Btw, you plugin misses chainability